Can't boot into linux on my laptop?
So, I have a transcend external HDD and have half used and decided to install linux in a partition.
So, i freed space and during installation, i created a root partation, swap partation and efi partation.I used one of my friends laptop for installation, and its works fine there ,its dell laptop.
In my asus Tuf dash F15 - nothing shows in boot option
Again, in another laptop it shows it is unbootable.
Whats the issue, i am kind of new to this !!

Perhaps hardware incompatibility?

I tried again in another hp laptop, it doesn't shows up in boot manager but it lets user to manually select efi partation, and i am able to boot there.


efi partation

Often EFI bootloader / boot manager is installed to a non-fallback path and relies on registration in the firmware's NVRAM for the firmware to be able to find and execute it.
Therefore, if that's the case here, once you move the drive to another machine, there will be no registration on new machine and its firmware will not be able to know what to execute / boot from it.
For a portable installation, you can simply copy / move the executable to the fallback path \EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI. Its current location might be something like \EFI\kali\grubx64.efi. (The paths are relative to the root of the EFI partition. Say you mount it on /mnt in a live environment, then it would be e.g. /mnt/EFI/kali/grubx64.efi)

Not every PC can boot from external USB Harddisk or SD Card. On other hand, ability of booting from internals SSD/HD and external USB Stick are standard today.
But some PCs like Dell Notebooks, you can also configure "boot from external USB" or like this, by your BIOS settings. So you can boot also from external USB SSD/HD.
